# How to search among multiple words by using a SearchView?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, searchview

I'm trying to search an SQLite database using SearchView. As of now, I can only search by one word.

e.g. "Hello my name is Bob, I have a Cat"
If I was to search one word from the text above ("Bob"), the whole line will be displayed.
However I would like the above text to also be displayed when searching for "bob cat", or "my name have". As this returns a blank list view.

This data is displayed in a list view.

```
private void searchUsers(SearchView searchDB) {

    Cursor cursor = myDb.searchUsers(searchDB);

    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(activity_symptcheck.this, "No data to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            listItem.add("Illness: " + "\n" + cursor.getString(1) + "\n" + "Symptoms: " + "\n" + cursor.getString(2) + "\n" + "Treatments: " + "\n" + cursor.getString(3));
        }
        cursor.close();
        myDb.close();
    }

    searchDB.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String searchTxt) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchTxt) {
            ArrayList<String> userslist = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String user : listItem) {
                if (user.toLowerCase().contains(searchTxt.toLowerCase())) {
                        userslist.add(user);
                    }
                }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity_symptcheck.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userslist);
            ListIllness.setAdapter(adapter);

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
public Cursor searchUsers(SearchView searchDB) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+COL_3+" LIKE '%"+searchDB.getQuery()+"%'"+searchDB.getQuery(), null);

    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your string into separate words and then dynamically build WHERE query for matching each word.

you can get list of all word by applying split on your search string by space.

```
String[] words = "search string".split("\\s")

String query = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+COL_3+" LIKE '%"+words[0]+"%'"

for(int i=1;i<words.length;i++){
    query += " AND '%"+words[i]+"%'"
}
```

*Updated with \\s*

Comment: you need to replace `" "` with `\\s`.

Comment: This should work, Check your logic if it have some other error. Let me know the problem you are facing so i can help

Answer (score 0):

If your splitting your input from your edit text by whitespaces and match that against your string you might get an better result

```
String[] searchTextArray = searchText.split();
for (String user : listItem){
    for (String part : searchTextArray){
        if (user.toLowerCase().contains(part.toLowerCase()){
            userlist.add(user);
            break;
        }
     }
}
```

Be aware ,this is untested code.

if your collecting all matches you can mark the matches in the names with spannablestrings i guess.

Answer (score 0):

If `getQuery()` returns the `String` to search for (like "Bob cat"), then you can construct your query like this:

```
String toSearch = getQuery();
String pattern = "%" + toSearch.replace(" ", "%") + "%";
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_3 + " LIKE " + pattern;
```

Comment: `'Hello my name is Bob, I have a Cat' LIKE '%bob%cat%'` is `TRUE` and `'Hello my name is Bob, I have a Cat' LIKE '%my%name%have%'` is also `TRUE`. So either you are doing something wrong or you did not explain what you need correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way :

- Make a class for filter input. when user clicks search button, assign all filter values to that class.
- Make a method inside model class, that returns true if any of the filter value matches. That takes filter class object as argument.
- Now when user clicks search button, iterate over each object in array. Call this method. If it returns true, add this object in new filter array.

**Example**

```
---- Filter class -----
class FilterTrucks {

String location;
int capacityStart;
int capacityEnd;
Arraylist<String> availability;

}

---- You model class -----
class Mytrucks {

String name;
String location;
int capacity;
String availability;

boolean matchFilter(FilterTrucks filter) {

boolean locationMatch = filterMatchesLocation(filter);
if(locationMatch)
return true;

boolean matchCapacity = filterMatchesCapacity(filter);
if(matchCapacity)
return true;

return false;

}

boolean filterMatchesLocation(FilterTrucks filter)  {
return location.contains(filter.location);
}

boolean filterMatchesCapacity(FilterTrucks filter)  {
return  (capacity >= filter.capacityStart ||  capacity <= filter.capacityEnd)
}

----- Your activity -----

Arraylist<Mytrucks> filterArray = new Arraylist<>();

filter_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

//create filter object from user selected fields
FilterTrucks filter = new FilterTrucks();
filter.location = txtLocation.getText().toString(); 

for(Mytrucks truck : arraylist) {
if(truck.matchFilter(filter)) 
    filterArray.add(truck);
}
    }
});

//use filter array to populate recycler view
```

Hope this helps.